# WIX: Uninstall is not happening properly

Tags: wix, uninstallation, rollback

I'm using WIX Installer with Custom Action.
In one scenario I'm unable to uninsall the product properly.
scenario:

1. installed base version appliation
2. trying to upgrade it.
3. An exception occured, rollback is done to previous version
   (we have overridden the wix rollback to do some custom action)
4. after rollback, I've tried to uninstall the base version installed product.
5. though it is saying uninstall succeeded, the actual product is not being uninstalled. all dlls are still there in registry. registry entry related to product is being removed and product is not there in control panel. But all the hosted websites are still there in IIS.

Please help me on resolving this issue.

Comment: if someone can give some hint also, helpful for us.

Comment: It's hard to guess what happens without additional details. Try to run upgrade and the following uninstall with verbose msi logging, it should give you a hint on what's happening in the system. My best guess is rollback isn't happening at it should and you end up with two applications using the DLLs: the old and the new ones. Therefore when you uninstall the base version, the files are not really removed from the system (because another app, *new version*, uses them).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following remove element in the same component where you are adding registry file and folder:

```
RemoveRegistryKey Action="removeOnUninstall" Root="HKLM" Key="..."

RemoveFile Id="Remove_file" Name="filename" On="uninstall" Property/Directory="" 

RemoveFolder Id="DeleteFolder" Property/Directory="" On="uninstall"
```